# Accelerometer Data Classification

Tags: python, classification, random-forest, accelerometer, train-test-split

I am trying to classify accelerometer data (sampled with a frequency of 100Hz) into 4 different transportation modes (0,1,2,3). I have 41 different CSV files, each representing a time series. I stored every file in a list called subjects. Each CSV-file looks as follows:

```
    # Check if the label mapping worked
    test = subjects[0]
    print(test.head())
    print(test.info())
    print(len(test))
```

```
              x         y         z  label
    0 -0.154881  0.383397 -0.653029      0
    1 -0.189302  0.410185 -0.597840      0
    2 -0.202931  0.408217 -0.490296      0
    3 -0.205011  0.407853 -0.360820      0
    4 -0.196665  0.430047 -0.147033      0

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 128628 entries, 0 to 128627
    Data columns (total 4 columns):
     #   Column  Non-Null Count   Dtype  
    ---  ------  --------------   -----  
     0   x       128628 non-null  float64
     1   y       128628 non-null  float64
     2   z       128628 non-null  float64
     3   label   128628 non-null  int64  
    dtypes: float64(3), int64(1)
    memory usage: 3.9 MB
    None

    128628
```

At first, I would like to start with implementing a Random Forest Algorithm. However I am not sure how to create the train and test dataset for this, as I have different CSV-files.

How can I create the train and test files for this task? At first I thought about concat all CSV-files together, but as each file represents a time series, I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough example of what you want to do:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report

# concat the list of your dataframes
df = pd.concat(list_of_your_dataframes)
print(df.head())

# Split the data into features (X) and target labels (y)
X = df[['x', 'y', 'z']]
y = df['label']

# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a Random Forest Classifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)

# Fit the classifier to the training data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the classifier's performance
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)

print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
print("Classification Report:\n", report)
```

Comment: Thanks! But now you are splitting the data randomly right? I am not sure if this is the correct way as every CSV file represents a single time series

Comment: yeah it's random but I don't see why it would be an issue if your CSVs contain data recorded at different times. can you explain more? does 41 different CSVs mean something else? for example 41 different subjects or 41 different accelerometers?